React, confused in useState
Can anyone explaine me please, just start learn React, I'm confused in one thing in this code:
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

function Car() {
  const [car, setCar] = useState({
    brand: "Ford",
    model: "Mustang",
    year: "1964",
    color: "red",
  });

  const updateColor = () => {
    setCar((previousState) => {
      return { ...previousState, color: "blue" };
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>My {car.brand}</h1>
      <p>
        It is a {car.color} {car.model} from {car.year}.
      </p>
      <button type="button" onClick={updateColor}>
        Blue
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Car />);

previousState , If we only called setCar({color: "blue"}), this would remove the brand, model, and year from our state,
so previousState concatenating them, but how previousState accessed brand, model and year? ewhen they were attributed to him?
previousState is not a keyword no?

The documentation already describes this.  Specifically: "If you pass a function [...] it will be treated as an updater function. It must be pure, should take the pending state as its only argument, and should return the next state."  In the function you're passing to setCar, the only argument to that function is called previousState in your code, and that argument contains the "current" state value.

thanks a lot for explanations.. makes sens

The callback variant of the state setter function consumes the current state, and produces a new immutable state.
Here is an explanation:
const updateColor = () => {
  // State setter callback gets the current value
  setCar((currentCar) => {
    // For a shallow object, this is not needed, but useful for nested objects
    const carCopy = structuredClone(currentCar);
    // Spread the existing car state, with the updated values
    const updatedCar = { ...carCopy, color: "blue" };
    // Return the new (imutable) state
    return updatedCar;
  });
};

Working snippet
Here is the React application in action:


const { Fragment, useState } = React;

function Car() {
  const [car, setCar] = useState({
    brand: "Ford",
    model: "Mustang",
    year: "1964",
    color: "red",
  });

  const updateColor = () => {
    setCar((currentCar) => ({
      ...structuredClone(currentCar),
      color: "blue"
    }));
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>My {car.brand}</h1>
      <p>
        It is a {car.color} {car.model} from {car.year}.
      </p>
      <button type="button" onClick={updateColor}>
        Blue
      </button>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<Car />);
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>




got it clear.. so grateful for answers

    setCar((previousState) => {
      return { ...previousState, color: "blue" };
    });

We can split this into:
setCar() and
(previousState) => { return { ...previousState, color: "blue" }; }

wich is an anonymus function. React call your function and set in the param the old state, so its not a keyword, its just the name you give to the old state.

As stated in the comment, if you pass a function to the updater react treat it as a pure function and the argument is the "current" state of the component. You are confuse by the previousState name but it's no reserve keyword. It's just there the make your life easier to understand what it contains.

using previousState is just a convention. You could just correctly written the updater like so.
setCar((p) => {
      return { ...p, color: "blue" };
    });


In this case:
(p) => {
      return { ...p, color: "blue" };
    }

Is just a bog standard javascript callback function. Where we pass an anonymous function as an argument to another function and it is called behind the scenes with a value passed as an argument.

Let me clear this confusition, when you call setCar((previousState) => { ... }), React internally retrieves the current state object ({ brand: "Ford", model: "Mustang", year: "1964", color: "red" }) and passes it as the previousState argument to the updater function. Inside the updater function, you can access and use the properties of previousState (brand, model, year, color) to compute the new state.
The spread operator (...previousState) is used to create a new object that includes all the properties of previousState. This ensures that the new state object retains the existing properties (brand, model, year) while allowing you to update the color property.
So, when you call setCar((previousState) => { return { ...previousState, color: "blue" }; }), the new state object will be { brand: "Ford", model: "Mustang", year: "1964", color: "blue" }.

basically what your code is doing :
// here you are defining an initializing a variable named car and in useState you are adding an object with different attributes.
  const [car, setCar] = useState({
    brand: "Ford",
    model: "Mustang",
    year: "1964",
    color: "red",
  });

So now we now that for you car variable it's an object and you are always going to have, brand, model, year and color.

If you do setCar({color: "blue"}) it will replace it with a new object.

However, if you wanted to update all the parameters of you object car you could do something like:
  setCar( brand: "Audi",
      model: "A4",
      year: "2024",
      color: "blue",);



and if you wanted to update only one value and leave everything else as it is you do
  const updateColor = () => {
    setCar((previousState) => {
      return { ...previousState, color: "blue" };
    });
  };

where previousState it's your current car object and by using the three dots (...) you are doing something called spread syntax and the value after the comma color: "blue" it's where you are telling react that you want to update the property color with the new value

so is basic sintax..) thanks
